# How to extract strings to constants in a reusable way

Tags: php, sonarqube, constants

Sonar is telling me, that i should replace a often used string (>2) with a constant to avoid a critical code smell.

I use sonata admin in my project and there are code lines like this

```
->add('test123', null, ['label' => 'Test label'])
```

The word "label" is very often used, but its due to the design of sonata admin.

The pattern to add fields is the same for all admin classes in my project. All admins containing the "label" word at least one time ...

But i don't want to write for each class almost the same constants, containing the same values.

I cant use constants in traits. I cant use constants in interfaces. I just can use constants in parent classes. But my parent class i am inheriting is a class from the vendor folder, i cant change.

It looks like this

```
class TestAdmin extends AbstractAdmin 
{
...
}
```

where AbstractAdmin is vendor and TestAdmin is my own implemented class.

Is the only and cleanest way to add another class between TestAdmin and AbstractAdmin? In my current opinion i want to avoid a too big inheritance-tree ... but if this is nevertheless a good practice, then i will change my mind ... thanks

Comment: As a workaround you could disable this rule for some particular files https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues

Comment: A workaround is not the solution i want to reach. I thought so far that every sonar rule makes sense in any way. I learned a lot from sonar rules in the past days, so disable rules is not the right way i think ... It's much more interesting to know if other developer are experiencing the same things and found already a solution or if they don't care about such things and take it as "a bad given design which cannot be changed" ... i'll try it with another abstraction layer between the "AbstractAdmin" and "TestAdmin" ... like "CustomAbstractAdmin" ...